# What drugs can keep you awake for long time?

Tags: sleep-deprivation, hallucinate-hallucogenic, stimulants, amphetamine, autopsy

I'm writing a story about someone who's poisoned with a drug which makes him not be able to sleep for several days. In order to make my story as realistic as possible I need to know a couple of things:

1) Does this type of drug actually exist? I think that amphetamines or modafinil can keep you awake but,

2) Can these drugs keep the effect for a long time (days)? I mean, the organism would start at a certain point and try to sleep, right?

3) If there's such a drug then after a long period of sleep deprivation the person would start to have certain symptoms. Could be hallucinations one of these symptoms?

4) And now even more complicated: is there any possibility that if the person dies could be no trace of the drug in an autopsy's toxicological analysis?

Answer (score 1):

The most popular drug that can keep people awake for long time is caffeine. Most caffeine pills contain a 200mg dose, about the same as the average 12-ounce cup of coffee.

Comment: Welcome to Health.SE. Since health is an important topic, the site has a strict policy that **all answers** should be [backed up with reliable references](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers) in order to provide the community with the means to assess the merit of the answer, regardless of the reader's background. *See [this list of reliable sources](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112/what-are-reliable-sources)*. If you still have trouble with this, feel free to visit the [help].